# Using an email address as imessage contact name

Tags: iphone

My friend is using her iphone only for imessages.  She is using her email address as her contact name.  So when I send her a message I type in her email address.  Whenever I send her a message using a device other than my iphone and I type in her email address will she still get it on her iphone or will it only go to her email account?

Comment: Is the device other than your phone using iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

iMessage is a service from Apple which works from iOS devices and Macs with OS X 10.8 and later only and is using the device's data connection rather than the regular phone connection.

Using the e-mail address with another device's text messaging system will most-likely result into an error telling you that the e-mail address entered is an invalid phone number.

Sending a message with ANY device as regular e-mail will result into your friend receiving the message as e-mail instead of an iMessage.